# Default Value Containing Special Characters in HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, drupal-6

I was trying to get a symbol like ® to be a default value for a text field,
I am trying to set the default by a javascript , but all i get is `&reg; or &amp;&reg;` in the text box, i am doing this from script as i am using drupal , so i dont have html files , i even trie ddefault value option in hook_form()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what exactly you're trying to do; maybe something like this?

```
// set the default value of yourTextField
yourTextField.defaultValue = '\u00AE';

// or set the actual value of yourTextField
yourTextField.Value = '\u00AE';
```

Comment: i was not using Unicode characters , i overlooked this and was tryin with & reg ; as in html , got it now